# Unity - why are materials with images glitching out? ONLY in the build?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

For weeks Ive had this problem trying to build my Oculus game to an executable build. Everything works in the editor but when I build, 80% my materials that have images/psd files as the diffuse and/or emission come out like this:

[image]

The build log gives me this, which I dont know what to make of:

[image]
[image]

I looked in graphics settings here and tried adding the standard shader in always included, and even tried pasting everything into a new scene:

[image]

But nothing works. And some images are working (see the blue screen with the thumbs up). But the rest do this. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are we talking Oculus Rift, or one of the mobile Oculus devices? (Gear VR/ Go)

Comment: Oculus Rift is the platform